# C++ How do I fill in two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, output

I just want to fill in two-dimensional array string values. e.g: array[5][6]

```
.X.... 
X..... 
XX.... 
.....X 
...X..
```

I tried to use `getline(cin, array)` but it makes cells:

```
.
X
.
.
.
. etc
```

Also, I tried to use `_getch();` but it doesn't output values I just entered. So, is there a way that makes input clearner?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is no different than any other array, except that it has two parts.

For example, if your array is 5x2, it means that you have 5 elements with 2 values in each:

```
int a[5][2] = { {0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6}, {4,8} };
```